# airflow db reset fails to drop table

Tags: python, airflow

The problem manifest itself when running `airflow db init` and appeared overnight (no change in setup). Is it a broken dependency?

The [link](https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8) suggests disconnection - but the error itself looks
more a failed table drop when running `airflow db reset [--skip-init]`.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table _alembic_tmp_dag_run already exists
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE _alembic_tmp_dag_run (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        dag_id VARCHAR(250), 
        execution_date DATETIME, 
        state VARCHAR(50), 
        run_id VARCHAR(250), 
        external_trigger BOOLEAN, 
        conf BLOB, 
        end_date DATETIME, 
        start_date DATETIME, 
        run_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (dag_id, run_id), 
        UNIQUE (dag_id, execution_date)
)

]
(Background on this error at: [https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8](https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8) )
```

```
apache-airflow                      2.3.3
apache-airflow-client               2.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql 1.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-ftp        3.3.1
apache-airflow-providers-http       4.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-imap       3.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite     3.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with alembic `1.11.0`, released 13h before this question was posted. `pip install alembic==1.10.4` resolves in the meantime that airflow requirements are fixes/codebase upgraded.

[Resolved in airflow 2.6.2](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/31313), install `pip install apace-airflow --constraint <url>` resolves.

e.g. `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.4/constraints-3.7.txt"` for Python 3.7